# What is "fluffy" in Serenity?

Tags: languages, firefly, serenity

In the ***Firefly*** series Joss Whedon often used linguistic devices such as Mandarin Chinese signs, curses, and other assorted phrases to indicate a removal in time and space.

To further this, he also introduced the usage of some words in English which seem to have followed some [semantic drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change).
There is one I have often puzzled over, which occurred in Inara’s boudoir at the school in the movie Serenity.

> The Operative: I have a warship in deep orbit, Captain. We locked onto Serenity's pulse beacon the moment you hit atmo. I can speak a word and send a missile to that exact location inside of three minutes.
>
> Capt. Malcolm Reynolds: You do that; you'd best make peace with your dear and *fluffy* lord.

What is the interpretation of *fluffy* in this context? Is this an example of semantic change or was it just a “throwaway” word.

Comment: Fluffy as in cuddly?  Like a fluffy stuffed animal.  That was my instinct.  Didn't think that was much of a drift.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Mal meant "fluffy" like a teddy bear, a comforting but fictional companion for a child.  This goes along with Mal's cynical view towards religion.  I don't have any confirmation of this interpretation so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: @Radhil That was my first impression also, but "fluffy" and "lord" are not exactly common collocations.

Comment: @Gandalf - no, but the general meaning of "good or pure" being sarcastically twisted into "fuzzy-wuzzies" or something similar is more and more common, and Mal... is exactly that kind of person.

Comment: Particularly given that Mal is an atheist by this point and considers God to be nothing more than a comforting tale that people tell to each other, not unlike a security blanket, or a fluffy teddy bear one gives to a child. (Which, upon reading *all* the comments, is basically exactly what @EldritchWarlord said.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mal seems to be [misquoting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21QEIYovTlo&feature=youtu.be&t=25s) Shakespeare (in this case [Henry V, Act 1, Scene 2](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/henryv/page_14.html))

> *And God forbid, my dear and **faithful** lord, that you should invent,
>   twist, or distort your interpretation*

The next couple of lines of Henry's speech are especially relevant under the circumstances.

> For God knows how many healthy men will shed their blood in support of
>   whatever you persuade me to do. So think carefully before you incite
>   me

---

"Fluffy" in this instance simply means "nice" or "gentle", albeit said with an atheist's lack of respect. We see a similar turn of speech in [Angel](http://www.buffyworld.com/angel/transcripts/080_tran.html), also co-written by Joss Whedon:

> **ANGELUS:** *Hey, man, you're preaching to the guy who ate the choir. Wait, it was you, wasn't it? You pulled just the wrong strings to make
>   them think it was their idea. Got 'em to yank that white, fluffy soul,
>   and stuff it in a jar, and then gone, baby, gone.*

Comment: An interesting take, particularly the quote from Angel, which would seem to indicate that it is not semantic drift in the future, but rather a linguistic quirk of Whedon himself. I'm going to let it ferment a while, but I am inclined to mark this off as the answer.

Comment: @Gandalf - He uses the word fluffy quite a lot; "*[ANYA](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/transcripts/087_tran.html): Oh, no. I'm sure it frisked about like a fluffy lamb.*", "*[Lorne](http://www.buffyworld.com/angel/transcripts/046_tran.html): The sky is blue, full of big, fluffy clouds."*, etc

Comment: He does seem to like that word. I wonder why?

Comment: @Gandalf - One of Whedon's trademarks is having his characters speak with an extra, redundant adjective. It makes the speech seem more organic and less scripted.